# Whenever I am trying to add a new data. I am getting ID as null in object referenced as parameter in mvc c# model first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, controller, devexpress

I am posting data as json object containing all the definitions exactly same as the model. 

But when I would enter the Add Function. I am getting all the other data except int? Id in the Model object defined as parameters. 
*What would be the reason behind this?? (Note: While posting the data. It Contains the ID value).*

```
     public class Model {
        public int? Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        }
        
        public bool Add(Model model)
        {
           // Not getting value for model.Id  ??
           // add function
        }
        
        <!--view:-->
        <script>
        function onRowInserting(e)
        {
          var formData = form.option("formData");
          var id = formData('form').dxform('instance')
                   .getEditor('Id').Options('value');
           var name = formData('form').dxform('instance')
                   .getEditor('Name').Options('value');

          var Model = {
            Id:id,
            Name: name
          };

          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify(Model)
          url: "../TestModel/Add",
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
          }); 
        }
        </script>
```

don't worry about script I have personally debugged in var as well as in MODEL.Id I am getting the correct value.
 
 Name and all the other values are correct in view and controller as well.
 
 ID value in model object passed as parameter in controller is having null value don't understand why??

Comment: do include the script that collects the data and sends / ajax

Comment: @JerdineSabio have you tested it yet in model first approach??